# RubyMine 4 debugger: need a reference to a high-level "how to" guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rubymine

I am trying to set up and use the debugger in RubyMine 4.  I am running Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3-p125 OS X.  I have the proper gems, and can set breakpoints, set up a configuration, etc.  But I am unsure of the workflow.

I am looking for a pointer to some documentation on how to actually use the debugger.  Links?  Screencast?  Tutorial?  Once I get going, I'll be all set.

(Edit, clarified my actual question).

Comment: Specify your OS, RubyMine Debug configuration type (attach a screenshot), provide the output of `gem list` and your application `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder  My question isn't what I need to do to fix my issue, it's whether someone knows of a resource that can help me get a handle on how to use the debugger.  I'll change the question title to reflect my actual question more accurately.

Comment: Place breakpoint, create Rails debug configuration, press Debug button in the panel, browser opens, navigate to a page that triggers breakpoint, see frames/locals in debugger. There is not much to explain here: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/running-and-debugging-2.html.

Comment: I knew there couldn't be much, but there were two things I was missing: 1) the help ... no, I am not an idiot (usually, but, maybe in this case..), and 2) how to set up to debug an app, so wasn't sure that this action would open the browser.  Pure conceptual misunderstanding.  TYVM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to debug a Rails application:

1. Place a breakpoint somewhere in the app code
2. [Create Rails Server Run/Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/running-and-debugging-2.html) (or use the existing one if the project was created in RubyMine)
3. Click on the **Debug** button in the toolbar
4. Rails server starts in debug mode
5. Browser with the app opens (or you open it manually if such option was disabled)
6. Navigate to the page that will trigger breakpoint
7. Observe the stack frame, locals, etc in the RubyMine Debugger pannel.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Rubymine online documentation: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/debugging.html